# Kafka : Cannot set up access control list with two brokers on same machine

Tags: java, ssl, apache-kafka

Here is what I want to do

1. Create a topic ssltest2
2. Set up acl for this topic. I intend to have a producer and a consumer
3. Run two brokers from my localhost, one open and the other secured
4. Run the producer and consumer to see if the acls actually work

Here is my setup. I followed [Apache Kafka - Security](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#security)

1. I create two server files. For the simple broker I have

   ```
   broker.id=0
   listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
   num.network.threads=3
   num.io.threads=8
   socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
   socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
   socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
   log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs
   num.partitions=1
   num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
   log.retention.hours=168
   log.segment.bytes=1073741824
   log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
   zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181
   zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
   ```

   For my second broker i want to have SSL authentication for clients. So i have

   ```
   broker.id=1
   listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9094,SSL://localhost:9093
   allow.everyone.if.no.acl.found=false
   ssl.client.auth=required
   ssl.enabled.protocols=TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1
   ssl.keystore.location=/path/to/server.keystore.jks
   ssl.keystore.password=localhost
   ssl.key.password=localhost
   ssl.truststore.location=/path/to/server.truststore.jks
   ssl.truststore.password=localhost
   num.network.threads=3
   num.io.threads=8
   socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
   socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
   socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
   log.dirs=/tmp/SSLserver/kafka-logs
   num.partitions=1
   num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
   log.retention.hours=168
   log.segment.bytes=1073741824
   log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
   zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181
   zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
   ```

   and i start them as separate processes. Both of them start up just fine.
2. Now i have also created SSL keys and self signed certificates for two clients. One producer and one consumer.

   The producer config that I will use is `producerclient.properties`:

   ```
   security.protocol=SSL
   ssl.truststore.location=/path/to/producer.truststore.jks
   ssl.truststore.password=producer
   ssl.keystore.location=/path/to/producer.keystore.jks
   ssl.keystore.password=producer
   ssl.key.password=producer
   ```

   and similarly for the consumer `consumerclient.properties`:

   ```
   security.protocol=SSL
   ssl.truststore.location=/path/to/consumer.truststore.jks
   ssl.truststore.password=consumer
   ssl.keystore.location=/path/to/consumer.keystore.jks
   ssl.keystore.password=consumer
   ssl.key.password=consumer
   ```
3. Next I created the new topic:

   ```
   kafka-topics.bat --create --topic ssltest2 --zookeeper "localhost:2181" --partitions 1 --replication-factor 1
   ```
4. Now I set up the ACL for this topic as:

   ```
   kafka-acls.bat --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181 --add --allow-principal User:abtProducer --producer --topic ssltest2
   ```
5. Finally, when I try to produce as:

   ```
   kafka-console-producer.bat --broker-list localhost:9093 --topic ssltest2 --producer.config ..\..\config\producerclient.properties`
   ```

When i try to push a message, say `test` I get

> [2016-04-20 13:44:36,633] WARN Failed to send SSL Close message  (org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer) java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
>           at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
>           at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
>           at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
>           at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
>           at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
>           at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.flush(SslTransportLayer.java:194)
>           at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.close(SslTransportLayer.java:161)
>           at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.close(KafkaChannel.java:45)
>           at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.close(Selector.java:442)
>           at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:310)
>           at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:256)
>           at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:216)
>           at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:128)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I have no idea what this is. What is wrong with my setup?

Comment: why the downvote and close vote? is the question too generic?

Comment: With my understanding there can be lot of things that can go wrong..   Can u try setting up just single broker on one machine and test first.. if that works.  Ref :https://github.com/Symantec/kafka-security-0.9

Comment: Not quite sure why others downvoted, your question tries to provide all needed information. BUT you should try to reduce all configs to the absolute minimum to reproduce your problem. Try to remove all lines from you config file, which are not bound to the problem. Remove the non-ssl configs. And provide some more details after which the problem occurs. Does it work without setting the ACL at all? (Probably this is too late for your problem, but helpful for the next time). If you solved your problem in the meantime, would be nice to know how you solved it.